# How can I find my DHCP nameservers?

Tags: dns

I configured my machine with DHCP. Where can I find the IP addresses of the name servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical location for the DNS resolvers on Linux is `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Since NetworkManager has taken over from `ifconfig` as the primary network management component, that file normally contains a single resolver, namely localhost:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
...
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

NetworkManager, through `dnsmasq`, provides this local DNS resolver.  `dnsmasq` is also the DHCP-client (and has various other roles), hence 'knows' the upstream DNS resolvers.

You can use `nmcli` (the NetworkManager command-line interface) to query its settings:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.103.0.24
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.103.0.23
```

In the GUI click on the network indicator, and select "Connection Information" from the menu.  The upstream DNS resolvers are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty complete information on a network interface using `nmcli` and you can narrow the output to the specific info you are looking for by piping it through `grep`

**For Ubuntu 14.04:**

`nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep DNS`

**For Ubuntu 16.04:**

`nmcli dev show eth0 | grep DNS`

Sources: respactive `man nmcli` pages and testing.

In both instances change **eth0** to your interface name which may be different than mine